# R iterate through list of dataframes to create new column

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list of dataframes `DFList`.  For every dataframe in `DFList` i would like to create a new column `X4`.

`Small Example`

```
X1 <- c(1,2,3,"X","Y")
X2 <- c(100,200,130,120,150)
X3 <- c(1000,250,290,122,170)
DF1 <- data.frame(X1,X2,X3)

X1 <- c(5,6,4,3,9)
X2 <- c(105,205,150,125,175)
X3 <- c(1500,589,560,512,520)
DF2 <- data.frame(X1,X2,X3)

DFList <- list(DF1,DF2)
names(DFList) <- c("DF1","DF2")
DFList
```

To create a new column by combining values from columns X1, X2, and X3 I created the following function.

```
MyFUN <- function(V) {
  X4 <- paste(V[1],":",V[2],"-",V[3], sep = "")
  return(X4)
}
```

However I am having trouble successfully running this function... I attempted the following but the desired X4 column is not being added to the dataframes contained in the list.

```
print(DFList)

for (DF in DFList){
  for (num in (0:length(DFList))){
    DF["X4"] <- lapply(DF[num], FUN = MyFUN)
  }
}

print(DFList)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop through the `list` elements and `transform` to create the `paste`ed components (assuming that we have only 3 columns and the column names are static

```
lapply(DFList, transform, X4 = paste0(X1, X2, X3))
```

---

If we have variable columns

```
lapply(DFList,  function(x) {x$newCol <- do.call(paste0, x); x})
```